# Using R with a forloop

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R, but have used MatLab pretty extensively and I have what I think is probably a relatively question.

I have a data set that is has 19 variable and has 14 observations. I want to write a for loop that takes the columns and loops over it. So for example `data$example` I want to use the values in `data$example` if possible.

It would look something like

```
for(i in data$example){ 
    Answer[i] <- (data$example[i+1])/(data$example[i])
}
```

Is this allowed in R? Because I currently just get NAs

Comment: please ignore the '\'

Comment: @Adam Warner while Michael's post answers your question, I would strongly advise you to adopt cole's approach.  In general for loops should be avoided at all cost in R.  This is because they are really slow, especially when compare to vectorized operations such as the apply family.  For your current problem, there will not be much of difference between a for loop or an apply approach.  Getting in the habit of using apply, however, is important.  I have experienced speeds up of a factor of 100 when using apply instead of for loops when numerous iterations are required.

Comment: Just a note here.  @Jacob H is not correct because the `apply` approach is not that much, if any more efficient than a `for` loop.  If you look at the source of the `apply` family of functions it's actually just using a `for` loop behind the scenes.

Comment: @Forrest R Stevens, yep you are right.  The apply function is a wrapper for the for loop.  Which is something I did forget!  That being said, the apply family does pre-allocate memory for you.  More generally, I think that it is important for new users of R, especially those coming from Matlab, to try and avoid for loops and opt for the built-in R functions when possible.  Many of these R functions, the apply family is not one of them, are vectorized.  Vectorizing your code, whenever possible, is the only way to ensure that your code runs quickly in R.

Comment: Forrest R. Stevens and @JacobH these are very interesting points that I was not aware of in R regarding for loops versus apply functions.  I find that I prefer using apply functions simply because the code is easier to write (once you get the hang of it) and especially when writing anonymous functions, it prevents pollution of the global environment with variables created just to index the loop on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the world of R! In the "R style", *apply functions are usually used in place of for and other conditional loops.  Try something like:

```
sapply(2:nrow(data)),function(x) data[x,'example'] / data[x-1,'example'])
```

A couple of things to note:  I'm using the `sapply` function which applies the function of its second argument to all of the elements in the first argument.  I'm using the first argument to index the data.frame (from 2 to the end, because we can't apply the function to the first row.  I'm using the second argument to create an "anonymous" function that carries out the operation.  Specifically, I'm using the `[` notation to index values in the data.frame, where the first value is the row number and the second value is the string representing the name of the variable.

One last thing using `data` as a variable name for you data is generally a no no in R.  It can create conflicts in the namespace and give you headaches later on.  I usually use `d` instead.

Comment: Thank you for response @cole. This method worked, I am still not exactly sure how but I can read up using ?sapply.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could avoid the `for` loop altogether (as an aside, the `apply` family of functions are rarely that much more efficient than a well written `for` loop) and use vectorized operations:

```
##  Using ts() you can lag arbitrarily, however it does not pad with NA's
##    and you will end up with an Answer that's one fewer items in length:
Answer <- numeric( lag(ts(data$example), 1) / ts(data$example) )

##  As an alternative, without the ts() calls but a hard-coded NA pad:
Answer <- c(data$example[-1], NA) / data$example
```

You can safely remove the `numeric()` call if you don't mind the data object remaining a `ts` object.  But doing things with vectorized operations in R is very, very important when possible as it greatly improves efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

R requires that you define the answer object where you are storing the results prior to the loop. You should also provide start and stop points for your iteration. If you instead provide a vector of values, it will use those values (you're getting NAs because the values in data$example are not rows in the data frame). So, for your example:

```
data <- cars
answer <- NULL
for (i in 1:NROW(data)){
  answer[i] = data$speed[i+1]/data$speed[i]
}
print(answer)

 [1] 1.000000 1.750000 1.000000 1.142857 1.125000 1.111111 1.000000 1.000000
 [9] 1.100000 1.000000 1.090909 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.083333 1.000000

[17] 1.000000 1.000000 1.076923 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.071429 1.000000
[25] 1.000000 1.066667 1.000000 1.062500 1.000000 1.000000 1.058824 1.000000
[33] 1.000000 1.000000 1.055556 1.000000 1.000000 1.052632 1.000000 1.000000
[41] 1.000000 1.000000 1.100000 1.045455 1.043478 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
[49] 1.041667       NA
```

Only the final result is missing because there is no i+1 for that final row. In contrast, what you did is more like:

```
answer2 = NULL
for (i in data$speed){
  print(i)
  answer2[i] = data$speed[i+1]/data$speed[i]
}
```

Which prints:

```
[1] 4
[1] 4
[1] 7
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
[1] 10
[1] 10
[1] 11
[1] 11
[1] 12
[1] 12
[1] 12
[1] 12
[1] 13
[1] 13
[1] 13
[1] 13
[1] 14
[1] 14
[1] 14
[1] 14
[1] 15
[1] 15
[1] 15
[1] 16
[1] 16
[1] 17
[1] 17
[1] 17
[1] 18
[1] 18
[1] 18
[1] 18
[1] 19
[1] 19
[1] 19
[1] 20
[1] 20
[1] 20
[1] 20
[1] 20
[1] 22
[1] 23
[1] 24
[1] 24
[1] 24
[1] 24
[1] 25
```

As you can see, these are not the locations where you were trying to store your result, but the values in the column `data$speed`. If we print `answer2` we get a similar pattern of NAs as you had because many row numbers are not present in data$speed.

```
print(answer2)
 [1]       NA       NA       NA 1.142857       NA       NA 1.000000 1.000000
 [9] 1.100000 1.000000 1.090909 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.083333 1.000000
[17] 1.000000 1.000000 1.076923 1.000000       NA 1.000000 1.071429 1.000000
[25] 1.000000
```

Comment: If you know the dimension of your `answer` object.  Make sure you pre-allocate it before looping.  For example, if I know after the loop my answer will have 4 variables with 10 observations, I would pre-allocate with `answer <- matrix(NA,10,4)`.  Iteratively concatenating is bad programming practice.